# CSS is not working as expected within the HTML file

Tags: html, css

The output is not appearing unless I provide text between the  tag. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks in advance

HTML CODE

```css
.Top {
        height: 20%;
        width: 80%;
        background: linear-gradient(#bc581e, #e27b36);
        border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
        box-shadow: inset -15px 0 #c15711;
        margin: 2% auto;
        position: relative;
    }
```

```html
<div class="Top">top</div>
```

JSBIN url : [CLICK HERE](https://jsbin.com/paqesukiwa/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: in JSBIN you set class `<div class="BreadTop"></div>` and not `.Top`

Comment: Try to add height in pixels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set `height` in `%` you have to define `height` to parent of element, In your case `html/body` are parents so set  `height:100%;` to parents

```css
html,body{
height:100%;
}
.Top {
        height: 20%;
        width: 80%;
        background: linear-gradient(#bc581e, #e27b36);
        border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
        box-shadow: inset -15px 0 #c15711;
        margin: 2% auto;
        position: relative;
    }
```

```html
<div class="Top"></div>
```

**Or** set `height` in `px` not `%`

```css
.Top {
        height: 20px;
        width: 80%;
        background: linear-gradient(#bc581e, #e27b36);
        border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
        box-shadow: inset -15px 0 #c15711;
        margin: 2% auto;
        position: relative;
    }
```

```html
<div class="Top"></div>
```

Comment: That helped, but can you please explain why % is not working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add `HTML & Body` `Height` `100%`

```
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
```

https://jsbin.com/ciqivicevu/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

approach 1:

Set actual size in px

```
height: 15px;
```

approach 2:
add

```
body{
  height: 100vh;
}
```

On another note
Poor fix:

```
<div class="Top">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided any height to parent elements.
define the width and height of the parent or to the `body` tag.

```
body{
  height:100%;
}
```

OR
Define a parent element and assign height to it.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="Top"></div>
</div>
```

OR

define the height in px for `.Top` class

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing your css like one below

```
 .Top {
     height: 20px;
     width: 80%;
     background: linear-gradient(#bc581e, #e27b36);
     border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
     box-shadow: inset -15px 0 #c15711;
     margin: 2% auto;
     position: relative;
  }
```

% here relates to % from parent .
So when you try specifying height in % , it looks for parent height to calculate it's %.
but in case of width(%) if parent is not present it would take a window width.